# Seg faults from Goldbach Conjecture in C

Tags: c

My program works for the most part, but any time I try to check a number > 6,576,900 I get a segmentation fault.

The weirdest part is that it actually runs past that point if started earlier, I just can't get it to start past that point.

Any tips on where the issue may lie, and ways I can correct it?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void goldbach(int);

int main(void) {
    int n;

    printf("Enter a number to start testing the goldbach conjecture: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    goldbach(n);

    return 0;
}

void goldbach(int n) {
    _Bool goldbachCheck = TRUE;

    //keep running as long as n can be expressed as the sum of two primes
    while(goldbachCheck == TRUE) {
        _Bool isPrime[n];

        for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            isPrime[i] = TRUE;
        }

        //Sieve of Erastosthenes method for calculating all primes < n
        for (int i = 2; i*i < n; i++) {
            if (isPrime[i]) {
                for (int j = i; i*j < n; j++) {
                    isPrime[i*j] = FALSE;
                }
            }
        }

        //counts number of primes found
        int primes = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (isPrime[i]) {
                primes++;
            }
        }


//store primes in an array
        int storePrimes[primes];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
            if (isPrime[i]) {
                storePrimes[count++] = i;
            }
        }

        //Checks if n can be expressed as the sum of two primes
        int start = 0;
        int end = count -1;

        while (start <= end){
            if (storePrimes[start] + storePrimes[end] == n) {
                break;
            }
            else if (storePrimes[start] + storePrimes[end] < n){
                start++;
            }
            else {
                end--;
            }
        }

        if (storePrimes[start] + storePrimes[end] == n) {
            printf("%i = %i + %i\n", n, storePrimes[start], storePrimes[end]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%i can not be expressed as the sum of two odd primes.\n", n);
            goldbachCheck = FALSE;
        }
        //Moves on to next even integer
        n+=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the segfault being thrown?

Comment: Any time I try to input a number > 6579000. Such as 6580000. I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) output.

Comment: But which line of code is causing the segfault? Have you tried attaching with a debugger?

Comment: @SeanKennedy But where? If it doesn't give you a stack trace saying where the error is happening, you'll need to debug. I'm guessing you're going off the end of an array somewhere, but you're doing so many array accesses all over the place, without running it its difficult to say.

Comment: running it through ddd with a value of 8000000 points to a problem with line 52 'storePrimes[count++] = i'

Comment: what's the value of `primes`? is it possible you are accessing beyond the end of the `storePrimes` array?

Comment: Stack overflow? ~6.5m bools + the primes could perhaps end up above 8mb

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are running into stack limit which usually is set to 8192k. You can find this by running

```
# ulimit -s
8192
```

You can either set this by specifying

```
# ulimit -s unlimited
```

and if you are running this on Mac you can set this to the max allowed on Mac (64 Mb) by running

```
# ulimit -a hard
```